# Why am i getting a status 400 after submitting my form?

Tags: api, next.js

I am trying to develop a simple app with Next.js but i am having issues with learning how to create an api.

This is my component to add an event with a form and a submit method that fetchs the data from the api.

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '@/components/Layout'
import styles from '@/styles/AddEvent.module.css'

export default function AddEventPage() {

  const submitHanlder = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = {
      title: e.target.title.value,
      description: e.target.description.value
    }

    fetch('/api/events', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    });
    console.log(formData)
  }



  return (
    <Layout title='Add New Event'>
        <h1>Add Event</h1>
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <form className={styles.form} action="" onSubmit={submitHanlder}>
            <label className={styles.label}  >Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" />
            <label className={styles.label} >Description</label>
            <input type="text" name="description"/>
            <label className={styles.label}htmlFor="">Date</label>
            <input type="date" />
            <button type='submit' >Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

And this is my api/events.js:

```
const handler = (req , res) => {

    if(req.method === 'POST'){
        return res.status(201).json({ message: 'evento agregado' });
    }
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'no se pudo agregar el evento' });
}

export default handler;
```

It is a simple handler that returns a message depending on the request method, but i am always getting the status 400 with the error message.

This is my request in the browser console:

```
{"title":"asdasd","description":"asdasdas"}
```

And my response:

```
message "evento agregado"
```

So it seems that is working. But when i go to localhost:3000/api/events it shows the following:

```
error   "no se pudo agregar el evento"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to print out what `req.method` is when the api gets called.

Add the following statement:

```js
console.log(req.method)`
```

Then have a look at what the server logs out.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to open `localhost:3000/api/events` in your browser the browser makes a GET Request, not a POST Request, to your api. That is the default behavior when opening a 'website'.

If you want to test your api you could use [Postman](https://www.postman.com) or an extension for Visual Studio Code. The [REST Client](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client) from Visual Studio Marketplace would probably be an option.